# Calling a Web Service in a main Domain from Sub domain

Tags: web-services

I have a ASP.net Webapplication hosted in a Sub domain in godaddy. The web application is calling a web service hosted in the main domain of my godaddy account hosting(root). my application makes calls to the web service and the web service responds as well.

problem is that my application in sub domain does not get the values fetched by the web service

I also tried creating a separate sub domain for the webservice, even then the same problem occurs. But when I hosted the web service in another separate domain  every thing works well.
Can anyone suggest me a solution please

Comment: Sounds like a CORS issue to me, but more details about the setup of the servers/domains are required to properly help you

Comment: Hi thanks. I have hosted the entire application in Godaddy. Not sure what kind of hosting godaddy uses (think its shared hosting). I have created a sub domain from main domain hosted the entire web application in a folder from root. I need to consume the web service hosted on the root of main domain

Comment: Sorted it out. I just Created another sub domain inside the sub domain and  and hosted the webservice.Then Consumed it from the application. then its working fine now..probably might be a issue with godaddy shared hosting-Thanks anyways